# Format ngui-auto-complete JSON objects

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am learning Ionic since few months. I have a list of hard-coded objects as:

```
    public Heroes = [{
    id : ‘1’,
    name : ‘John Smith’
    },{
    id : ‘2’,
    name : ‘Peter Parker’
    },
    {
    id : ‘3’,
    name : ‘Bruce Wayne’
    }
   ];
```

I am using, autocompleteListFormatter as:

```
   autocompleteListFormatter = (data: any): SafeHtml =>{
     let html = <span>${data.id}</span>;
     return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
    }
```

and, my HTML file looks like this:

```
    <ion-content padding>
       <input ngui-auto-complete
       [(ngModel)]="model1"
       [source]="Heroes"
       [open-on-focus]="false"
       display-property-name = "id"
       [list-formatter] = "autocompleteListFormatter"
       placeholder="enter text"/>
          {{ model1 | json }}
   </ion-content>
```

When I run this, I get the desired output.

```
{ “id”: “1”, “name”: “John Smith”}
```

However, I would like those curly brackets removed, and get these data in nicely HTML formatted without Id and Name field, like:

**1 

John Smith**

This must be simpler than I thought, but I have been looking for it for 2 days, and could not find a way. If someone knows the way, please guide me.

Comment: You can just do `{{model1.id}}` and `{{model1.name}}` right? is that not working?

Comment: It gives a runtime error:
Cannot read property 'id' of undefined.
 I have defined model 1 as,
  
       model1: any;

Comment: Do `{{model1?.id}}`

Comment: thank you, it worked. Finally!

Comment: how can I get the image for each selected heroes, like, if I select Bruce Wayne, this should show as: 1, <img> file and Name. 
Currently I am hard coding in the typescript as:
img: document.getElementById("Bruce_wayne") as HTMLImageElement, where the image file is uploaded in the IMG folder.